# How to go about login and logout in phonegap and JQM

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

Good day, 
I am new to phonegap and JQM...
I have a problem with phonegap and JQM.i did a login and logout application but the backbutton on android being the secure page back after I logout, instead of exiting the application or do something else ... Secondly, how will I remove backbutton event in phonegap...thirdly, must I control the backbutton in my application?

Comment: You should handle the backbutton in each layout/view you create it.
for example if you handle it inside the application just to go back in history, when it goes back to the login form it will stay in the page because it will try to go back  not to exit from the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In case you want backbutton to exit an app in one page and in other to act as a real back button you should use this:

   ```
           document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

   function onBackKeyDown() {
       if($.mobile.activePage.is('#loginpage')){
                    navigator.app.exitApp(); // Exit app if current page is a login page
       }
       else {
           navigator.app.backHistory(); // Go back in history in any other case
       }
   }
   ```
2. To remove/prevent a backbutton event use this:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   }, false);
   ```
3. And yes you must control your backbutton app event.